# Hydrogen and deuterium exchange

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Is this a valid mechanism? I think it is. It is just a simple acid base mechanism.

Could I increase yield though by using a stronger base than heavy water? Perhaps heavy sodium hydroxide? Or is chloroform sufficiently acidic?

[image]

Comment: The mechanism is sound, but be certain, that there will be an equilibrium and a statistical distribution of the involved species.

Comment: It would help to know more about the reaction conditions. I would not expect this reaction would happen in plain water at room temperature, but maybe my intuitions are wrong.

Comment: CCl3- is unstable and almost always forms :CCl2/Carbene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in making deutero-chloroform, there are [better ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroform#Deuterochloroform) to do it.

From a purely mechanistic standpoint, chloroform isn't a very strong acid ($\ce{pKa \sim 15}$) so $\ce{D2O}$ is unlikely to deprotonate it at a useful rate.  Further, chloroform isn't very soluble in water making your desired reaction even less likely (but you could engineer your way around this problem by using a phase transfer catalyst).

Your suggestion to use a stronger base is reasonable, but the problem you run into here is that a different reaction is brought into play.  Specifically, once a stronger base like potassium *t*-butoxide (in *t*-butanol) is used, dichlorocarbene formation occurs.  Once the trichloromethylcarbanion is formed, it quickly ejects $\ce{Cl^-}$ to form dichlorocarbene.  Dichlorocarbene is an extremely energetic species and would quickly react with whatever else is around - perhaps the t-butanol to produce dichloromethyl-t-butyl ether.

Comment: Deprotonation at a useful rate or a useful extent?

Comment: I'd say the rate of deprotonation (or reaction) would be extremely low and therefore the extent of deprotonation (or reaction) would be extremely low.